# Dynamically show / hide apex:column in pageblocktable

Tags: visualforce

I need to dynamically show / hide apex:column  in pageblocktable. I found a code which was working for datatable which uses column index to hide a column but not for pageblock table  because datacolumn index is not applicable in pageblocktable.

My visualforce markup:

#### **Opportunities**

```
          <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!oppList}" var="cp"  id="opportunityTable">



            <apex:column headerValue="Opportunity Number" >
              <apex:commandLink value="{!cp.CXT_Opportunity_Number__c}" action="{!showRecord}" target="_blank" immediate="true">

              </apex:commandLink>
            </apex:column>

            <apex:column headerValue="Account Name" id="aCol" >
              <apex:commandLink value="{!cp.Account.Name}" action="{!showRecord}" target="_blank" immediate="true">
                <apex:param name="rId" value="{!cp.Account.Id}" assignTo="{!selectedId}"/>
              </apex:commandLink>
            </apex:column>



            <apex:column headerValue="Billing Contact" >
             <apex:commandLink value="{!cp.CXT_Billing_Contact__r.Name}" action="{!showRecord}" target="_blank" immediate="true">
                <apex:param name="rId" value="{!cp.CXT_Billing_Contact__r.Id}" assignTo="{!selectedId}"/>
              </apex:commandLink>
            </apex:column> 

         </apex:pageBlockTable> 
        </apex:pageBlock>
       </apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: Add code to your question whatever you have tried so far

Comment: i have followed steps in following link.https://datatables.net/examples/api/show_hide.html

Comment: Can you post that dynamic condition? I know row index is not there, but same condition should be applicable

Comment: But i need  column index , var column = table.column( $(this).attr('data-column') );
 
        // Toggle the visibility
        column.visible( ! column.visible() );.

Comment: .column is not applicabe in pageblocktable. Is there any other way?